# Setting up Dev environment for Java development (Q.1)

Tags: java, tomcat, ide, installation

**1st part**

Never worked on team who uses different IDE for one project.. (But our team right now does that)
Never tweaked Ant Script of IDE, or wrote any Ant script..

I am Netbeans user, (since last 2 years) and ultimately want to become independent of IDEs (except for coding and code completion) .. like deploying, building

So I want some suggestions.. that how you work and what should be the ideal strategy for doing this..

**2nd Part**

 Please Help me out in sorting this problem, I don't want to use Tomcat in Netbeans.. takes lots of time in change-deploy-run cycle..(Everyone does not have fast machine). Instead i want to use Jetty, so now i have to run from console (or is it possible to run it in netbeans?? ), is there any tool which shows log output like IDE output window??

Cheers,

Comment: I would suggest posting two separate questions for part 1 and part 2.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion thomas.. i put it together because i thought both are relevant. Part 2 is one point of Part 1. But I can also put link to the previous question.. And already i got answers on both.. so, i am not doing for this question.. but will take care from now onwards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really only a part1 answer, and I also suggest splitting this into 2 questions.

The key to using different IDEs is to make sure none of your build/code is IDE dependent. The most typical problem is that you check in the file containing the application's classpath (the .classpath file in eclipse for example). Instead, you should use an external dependency management system such as maven or ivy (ivy works if you use ant, but maven is both a build tool AND a dependency management system so I would recommend maven if you can). Any IDE worth its weight will have plugins to support ant, ivy and maven, so as long as the developers have the plugin, they just point to the appropriate ant or maven build files. Maven's website is http://maven.apache.org/ and Ivy's website is http://ant.apache.org/ivy/.

Comment: I have started using Maven.. Its cool.. but have to understand lots of new concepts like Snapshot, local repository, plugin etc. But its really cool.. and very useful.. :)

Comment: Yes, there are definitely some new concepts in maven to learn, but the user guide http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html might help. Once you get over the initial learning curve, in my opinion, you'll wonder how you ever did without it, and writing ant builds will become a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1):

part2:

for the second part, consider you can only gain about 4-5 seconds when switching from tomcat to jetty.

typically the startup of a servlet container takes 30-60 seconds. for a real speed improvement consider using [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/). this allows you to see most changes in code instantly.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for the build (and everything else maven can do) and the IDE of choice for coding. Eclipse, IDEA, Netbeans, they all integrate with Maven.
- AFAIK, there is still no server plugin in Netbeans for Jetty (see [Issue 153500](http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=153500)). But it should be possible to start Jetty in debug mode and to attach a remote debugger from Netbeans. Or you could use maven and the [maven jetty plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) :)

Comment: Thanks Pascal for Maven Jetty plugin info.. 
& by the way, you name is cool.. (a programming language name :) )